# Centered perspective in css

Tags: html, css, webkit

is there any way to make the perspective of an element in HTML centered in the middle of the screen, so that the perspective point is not moved when you are scrolling...?

Thanks

EDIT:
Here is a small picture of my idea...
The element would be visible from the top and become visible from the bottom as you scroll down.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W84Me.png

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: its called `position:fixed;`

Comment: The actual 3d element should be moving with the side but the perspective should be fixed in one point.

Comment: so you should be more clear in your question.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "3D element" and "moving with the side but [...] fixed in one point". Could you please elaborate? Otherwise, a picture would be great to help us understand the issue.

Comment: For instance if there were a rotated element attached to another element then you could see it from the top when it is on the bottom of the page but when you scroll down you can see its bottom.

Comment: I'm with Zhihao on this one. A single HTML element doesn't have "persective" it's a 2-D construct. So you'd need a series of elements grouped to give classic perspective.

Comment: handle window.onscroll, do the math and move stuff yourself?

Comment: I could do that but I hoped there were an easier solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While traditionally, HTML Elements are 2D boxes only, since CSS3 there is the `transform` property which lets you transform the boxes in 3D space.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

This allows for such perspectives. But since only few browsers let you choose a perspective projection (only orthogonal), you may have to create the transformation matrix yourself. You may find tutorials and formulas for that in most modern OpenGL tutorials, for example.

Only problem left is show a different image from the bottom, since in HTML, an element looks the same from both sides (only mirrored). Maybe you can position 2 elements slightly above each other to get two different faces.

Also, you will need JS to move around the object on the screen.

Maybe you better use some modern technique like canvas or WebGL to do this, since HTML is not really made for 3D.

Comment: I've already worked with transformations before but I was hoping that you could set the perspective to the middle of the screen and not to the middle, top... of an element.

Comment: Nope, JS is your only hope then. Also, you could have told us so in the question! Saying you talk about the perspective property or something. It's always good to know what the asker already knows about the problem. Try to be more specific next time :)